# How can I fix this Implicit Coercion error in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, physics

I'm playing with a [Physics Engine for AS3](http://www.cove.org/ape/) and the code below is basically the hello world example. However, I made a slight change by declaring the property "ball" as a WheelParticle at the beginning of the class definition. (forgive my terminology if it's wrong). Before, it was declared inside the constructor as

```
var ball:WheelParticle = new WheelParticle(...);
```

and that worked fine. But now, trying it my way I get the error

> Implicit Coercion of a value of type
>   org.cove.ape.WheelParticle to an
>   unrelated type Class |
>   ball:WheelParticle = new... etc etc
>
> "illegal assignment to class
>   WheelParticle"

So I'm thinking my declaration `public var ball:WheelParticle` should be something else. But what?

Anyway, here's the code. It's quite short. I would refer to the documentation, but there is none. None that I can find anyway.

package{

```
    import org.cove.ape.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.Sprite;    

    public class Bounce extends Sprite {

         public var ball:WheelParticle;

    public function Bounce() {

        stage.focus = this;
        stage.frameRate = 100;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, run);

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveLeft);

        APEngine.init(0.3);
        APEngine.container = this;
        APEngine.addMasslessForce(new Vector(0,2));

        var defaultGroup:Group = new Group();
        defaultGroup.collideInternal = true;

        var ball:WheelParticle = new WheelParticle(250,10,40, false, 1, 0.7, 0.1);
        defaultGroup.addParticle(ball);

        var rp:RectangleParticle = new RectangleParticle(250,300,300,50,0,true);
        defaultGroup.addParticle(rp);


        APEngine.addGroup(defaultGroup);
      }

      private function moveLeft(e:Event):void{
          ball.speed += 1;
    }

      private function run(evt:Event):void {
         APEngine.step();
         APEngine.paint();
      }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the `WheelParticle` class (along with every other class you need) explicitly as:

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

import org.cove.ape.APEngine;
import org.cove.ape.Group;
import org.cove.ape.RectangleParticle;
import org.cove.ape.Vector;
import org.cove.ape.WheelParticle;

    public class Bounce extends Sprite {
```

That missing import is the most likely cause of your error. Also, note that your sample code has a small glitch.

```
 public class Bounce extends Sprite {

     public var ball:WheelParticle;
```

declares a member variable  for class `Bounce` of type `WheelParticle` called `ball`.

```
var ball:WheelParticle = new WheelParticle(250,10,40, false, 1, 0.7, 0.1);
```

Creates another variable with same type and same name but local to the constructor of `Bounce`. And this one shadows the former. If you want to use the member variable use:

```
ball = new WheelParticle(250,10,40, false, 1, 0.7, 0.1);
```